# mget in batch script does not work

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

i'd like to create a batch script which logs on a ftp-server and copies some files to a remote folder. but my script does not work. mget runs into a timeout (has to be terminated manually).

i'm starting ftp connection with ftp.bat:

```
ftp.exe -s:getdata.bat
```

getdata.bat:

```
OPEN host-ip
user
password
lcd "C:\tmp"
cd config
mget C1000.xml
close
```

starting, logging in and changing the directory works but getting the file doesn't work. nothing happens until i end the script manually. any hints?

regards,
michael

Comment: What did you want to do with this file Upload to server or Download it into your computer ?

Comment: Show us the output of the `ftp.exe`.

Comment: Also, note that you write *"copies some files to a remote folder"*, but you use `mget`, which is for downloading, not uploading.

Comment: I'd like to download the file to my computer (this is meant to be the remote folder).  Here's the output of ftp.exe: http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=3b9654-1461656268.jpg

Answer (score 2):

`mget` prompts for user confirmation for each file it finds, even when you only specify one specific file.

To get around this, you can either use `get` if you know the file name, or you can use `prompt` to disable the interactive prompt before you use `mget`.

```
OPEN host-ip
user
password
lcd "C:\tmp"
cd config
prompt
mget C1000.xml
close
```